# How to delete item from session Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how can i delete data from session in laravel. I do not want delete all data by clicking single delete button. I have delete button for each data, so want to delete one by one. my current code is as follows:

```
public function deleteProduct(Request $request){
    $id = $request->productId;// this id i want to delete which i get from view
    $products = $request->session()->get('product');

    foreach ($products as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value['id'] == $id)
        {
            unset($products [$key]);
        }
    }

    //then you can redirect or whatever you need
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

i tried this as well

```
foreach ($products as $product)
{
    if ($product->id == $id)
    {
        $products->forget($product);
    }
}
```

My data in session is in below format

```
[
{
id: 2,
name: "Marlene Reichert",
description: "Debitis asperiores sed sit assumenda unde quo natus. Consequatur est labore tenetur quae. Eius distinctio ea omnis aspernatur porro earum quae.",
category_id: 3,
price: 76,
image: "http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=71",
created_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
updated_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
qty: 1
},
{
id: 6,
name: "Kaylin Emard",
description: "Et aperiam omnis nam iure id non fugiat. Excepturi voluptatem ipsam magnam. Esse asperiores ducimus enim et.",
category_id: 8,
price: 14,
image: "http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=17",
created_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
updated_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
qty: 1
},
{
id: 5,
name: "Prof. Iliana Mohr",
description: "Autem sequi esse laudantium ut ut explicabo enim. Corporis cupiditate dolorum et ratione sequi architecto. Vitae enim ex hic nihil.",
category_id: 2,
price: 207,
image: "http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=99",
created_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
updated_at: "2019-07-16 10:12:27",
qty: 1
}
]
```

In my network tab, i got following error when i clicked the delete button

```
{message: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fresh/app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php"
line: 33
message: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"
trace: [{file: "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fresh/app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php",…},…]
0: {file: "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fresh/app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php",…}
1: {function: "deleteProduct", class: "App\Http\Controllers\ProductController", type: "->"}
2: {,…}
```

on dd()

```
$id = $request->productId;
    $products = $request->session()->get('product');
    dd($products);
```

In my network tab i got this

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#216
    +"id": 1
    +"name": "Keyshawn McDermott Sr."
    +"description": "Error aut quia id dolorem est aut doloribus nesciunt. Quod nihil tenetur ea id voluptas molestias id. Debitis amet dolor est fugiat sed autem."
    +"category_id": 1
    +"price": 59
    +"image": "http://loremflickr.com/400/300?random=36"
    +"created_at": "2019-07-16 10:12:27"
    +"updated_at": "2019-07-16 10:12:27"
    +"qty": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: You are updating and not deleting?

Comment: before the `foreach`, can you `dd($products);` and show the response

Comment: So what is the actual structure and content of $products …?

Comment: Are you storing JSON inside session ??

Comment: Updated . please have a look

Comment: try `foreach ($products as $key)
        {
            if ($key['id'] == $id) 
            {                
                unset($products [$key]);            
            }
        }`

Comment: @BundayyOlayinka i think my session data is in collection so i can't use that

Comment: `$products` is an array according to your `dd` so I expect it to work. what error are you getting now?

Comment: {message: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()", exception: "ErrorException",…}

Answer (score 1):

`session::forget()` calls `Illuminate\Support\Arr::forget()`, which

> Remove one or many array items from a given array using "dot" notation.

so just build key to access single element in session array multilevel structure.

```
public function deleteProduct(Request $request){
    $id = $request->productId;

    // Cycle through array from session.
    foreach ($request->session()->get('product') as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value->id == $id)
        {
            // Remove unwanted sub-key from array
            // using the dot (.) notation to access nested items
            $request->session()->forget('product.' . $key);
            // sure there's no duplicate id's
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$request->session()->forget('product');` is to remove the entire key from session, and you do not want that. So...

> how can i delete data from session in laravel.

In your case, you do:

```php
public function deleteProduct(Request $request){
    $id = $request->productId;

    // Get the array from session.
    $products = $request->session()->get('product');

    // Remove unwanted key from array.
    foreach ($products as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value->id == $id)
        {
            unset($products[$key]);
        }
    }

    // Override the session.
    $request->session()->put('product', $products);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

If one day you add the `deleteAllProducts()` feature in your system, for example, then you're good calling `$request->session()->forget('product');`

Comment: got error {message: "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array",…}

Comment: if your data structure is as you described, then it has no reasons to fail... got the feeling your session is messed, trying resetting it... calling `request()->session()->flush()` from anywhere will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
$request->session()->forget('product');
```

Comment: it removes all product, i need to remove one product at a time

Answer (score -2):

you can't use foreach for an array instead use the for loop

```
for($x = 0;$x<sizeOf($products);$x++)
{
  $product = $products[$x];
  #then do your manipulation here
}
```

Comment: _you can't use foreach for an array..._ Why do you think so?

Comment: *you can't use foreach for an array...* Yes you can, foreach construct is for iterations just as for is :)